# Jquery Animated Drop in of Logo

Tags: jquery, animation, drop-down-menu, onload

Im wanting the logo on [Gone Freelancing](http://gonefreelancing.com) to be and animated drop in on page load by Jquery, like when you click more for the modal. Once i learn how to do this i will create the same effect for the map markers only to drop in. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Ive searched google and can only find fade's

Your help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance, Roy
http://roybarber.com

Comment: Did you look in Google about it? what do you want exactly to know?

Comment: Hi Sam as mentioned above "Ive searched google and can only find fade's" im wanting a starting point to get the logo moving in, then some refrence of effects / speeds where i can learn to do it myself. Regards Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make it a separate object (i.e. absolute-positioned) that can move up and down without disrupting the remainder of the page. Remember the CSS "top" value when it looks all right. This will be the value where you slide the element to.

Then, set the "top" of the object to some negative amount (i.e. -500px) and use this code to make the div (with assumed id of "logo") slide down

```
$("#logo").load(function(){
    $('#logo').animate(
       {top:'400px'}, 
        100, // speed of animation in milliseconds
        function() {
           // Do something when animation is complete
        }
    );
});
```

You can read more about JQuery custom animations here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thanks, will doc ready give enough time for the images to load?

Comment: Good point. Then better use $("#logo").load(). I've updated my post.

Clarification: the doc.ready() will fire when the DOM is ready, and before the contents are loaded. Thus, we use .load() to ensure that the image is loaded before we slide it.

Comment: Fantastic everything works :) i will now split the logo up and have the 3x pins dropping in at seperate speeds, is there a way to add a delay? say pin1 100ms pin2 200ms etc?

Comment: Great! And yes, the delays are certainly possible. I think you could best do this with setTimeout(showpin1, 200); setTimeout(showpin2, 300); setTimeout(showpin3, 300); See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout for more info on setTimeout! Another option would be to chain the animations in the part that I commented with //Do something when animation is complete

Comment: Fantastic, when entering the new code it never worked. but the previous doc ready does work

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a very old thread but having the same question this answer worked however, the OP mentioned that the `$("#logo").load(function()` portion did not work but the `document.ready` did.

I encountered the same problem, so I am hoping someone might explain why the .load might be failing to execute in the code accepted by the OP.

Comment: Hi Robert, The difference was doc ready allowed for the pin image to preload, where .load just fired the animation on launch.

Comment: @RoyBarber Thanks, does the position of the script in the code matter like it does in javascript? Had the .load option been placed at the end of the document or somewhere after the DIV containing the IMG would it have worked then?

Comment: As long as it follows the normal hierarchy, define jQuery then your custom JS you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, set the logo you want to drop in like `top:-1000px` which is enough to stay off the visible screen. (position:absolute off course). And then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropin').animate({'top':'0px'}, 300);

});
```